# Symfony Test - Testing database with data to check Show($id) Feature

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

Could someone explain me how can I add some entities in to database for test purpose?
I want to test that endpoint /show/{id} show correct response, but to check that i need to have a entity in test database so i could download his data.

Im using last version of Symfony, Doctrine and PHP Unit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for Integration tests with symfony and you will face prerequisites (fixtures, test database, api call via `WebTestCase` class, ...).
It's a bit longer to explain in details, so all you want is in this page: https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing.html